# How to push data in object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, object, redux

I'm using Redux in my React App, and I need to put data to object (using action).

I have such reducer and action:

```
        case GET_USER_DATA: {
            return {
                ...state,
                user: action.value // user - is object
            }
        }

//my action
        export const getUserData = (value) => ({type: 'GET_USER_DATA',value})
```

And then I need to put data to my Redux state using action, but it not works, can anybody explaine me how to do this?

func:

```
    authListener() {
        fire.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
          console.log(user);
          if (user) {
            getUserData(user) // I need to put it here
            localStorage.setItem('user', user.uid);
          } else {
            getUserData(null)
            localStorage.removeItem('user');
          }
        });
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you added this function in mapDispatchToProps so that it can get the dispatch function and reducer can be called?

```
const mapStateToProps = (state: any) => {
    return {
        //any data from state
    };
};

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch: any) {
    return bindActionCreators({
        getUserData
    }, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(YOUR_COMPONENT_NAME);
```

You can now call the function as

```
props.getUserData(user);
```